# SVG with HTML5 video text fill

Tags: html, css, svg

So I have been trying to create and SVG Text Logo that displays an "embedded" mpg4 in the letters. At first I used Adobe Illustrator and created and SVG of my logo, while this gave me a great 100% width responsive logo on my page, I could not include a video element in the SVG in any way.

So now I got a Didot web font and am just using a text SVG, I copied and pasted code from F12 tools from this demo: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedTextFills/index22.html

What I am trying to do now is figure out how to make this logo larger and 100% width responsive to screen width changes.

When I edit `font:` of the CSS class `.wrap` I can get larger text but there is a fixed width on the SVG itself that cuts off the text on large screen devices and I cannot figure out. I don't think it relates to the video natural width and height.

What happens is when I change my browser to a large desktop size, the right size of my text is cut off:
[image]

I am been changing the values of the SVG `viewbox` attribute but I cannot seem to conceptualize the nature of the `viewbox` `width=600` and `height=300`, especially with the fact that there is a nest SVG within the parent SVG.

Even after reading this article: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html#viewbox, I am still having trouble grasping if the `viewbox` values are playing a role in my issue.

I actually don't think I need to change the values in the `viewbox` attributes of the two `SVG` elements. Perhaps it is the em calculations that is causing issues in relation to the `SVG` `text` element calculations:

```
 <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".35em" class="text">
                        Couture Book
                    </text>
```

```css
.mask__shape
    {
        fill: white;
    }

   
    .content
    {
        padding: 0 1em;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .wrap
    {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        font: 700 2.5em/1 'Dido';
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: left;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 80px 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    }

    .box-with-text
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    .text-fill
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    svg:not(:root)
    {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .svg-defs
    {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }

    .svg-inverted-mask
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }

    .shape--fill
    {
        fill: #fff;
    }

    .text--transparent
    {
        fill: transparent;
    }
```

```html
<div class="content">
        <div class="wrap">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 600 300" class="svg-defs">

                <!-- Symbol with text -->
                <symbol id="s-text">
                    <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".35em" class="text">
                            Couture Book
                        </text>
                </symbol>

                <!-- Mask with text -->
                <mask id="m-text" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">

                    <rect width="100%" height="100%" class="mask__shape">
                    </rect>
                    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#s-text" class="mask__text"></use>

                </mask>
            </svg>

            <div class="box-with-text">

                <!-- Container for video -->
                <div class="text-fill">
                    <video class="video" src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedTextFills/img/bokeh2.mp4" autoplay="" loop=""></video>
                </div>

                <!-- Visible SVG -->
                <svg viewBox="0 0 600 300" class="svg-inverted-mask">
                    <rect width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#m-text)" class="shape--fill"></rect>
                    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#s-text" class="text--transparent"></use>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: With SVG viewBox is how big the contents appear within a fixed size object. width and height is how big the object itself appears.

Answer (score 0):

Work out how big your text is.  If it is 500x100, then make your viewBox:

```
viewBox="0 0 500 100"
```

I'm not sure why you are positioning your text at `x="50%" y="50%"`.  That seems a bit odd.  The `x` and `y` coordinates, in a text element, set the position of the start of the baseline.  So again, if your text is 100 high, then you probably want to set the coordinates to something close to:

```
x="0" y="100"
```

Comment: What is the unit of measure in the viewbox, pixels (px)?

Comment: It's whatever is in your document.  Effectively they are pixels, but only if the document ends up being scaled 1:1.  If your viewBox is `"0 0 100 100"` and you make your SVG `width="50 height="50"`, then each unit in the SVG will be equivalent to half a pixel (when rendered)

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using 'rem' for the font size, set on the parent element.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little please?